# StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, client

I have a class Serializer

```
public class Serializer {

private Serializer() {}

public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    out.writeObject(obj);
    return b.toByteArray();
}

public static Object deserialize(byte [] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (bytes == null) return null;
    ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(b);
    return in.readObject();
}
}
```

My client sends data through

```
private static DataInputStream in;
private static DataOutput out;
...
out.writeInt(bytes.length);
out.write(bytes);
```

I read it this way

```
int length = in.readInt();
            if (length > 0) {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
                in.readFully(bytes);
                byte[] result = sp.processInput(bytes);
            }
```

And then when I try to deserialize my Person object(serializable) it throws me an error

```
Person person = (Person) Serializer.deserialize(bytes);
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 03ACED00
at model.Serializer.deserialize(Serializer.java:22)
```

Person class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
private String creationDate;
private String name;
private String birthDate;
private String city;
private String phoneNumber;
private String email;
private String university;
private String place;
private String reason;
private SerializableImage photo;
private boolean attended;
```

I can't use ordinary image because it's not serializable, so I came up with this class.

SerializableImage class

```
public class SerializableImage implements Serializable {
private int width, height;
private int[][] data;

public SerializableImage(Image image) {
    setImage(image);
}

public void setImage(Image image){...}
public Image getImage() {...}
```

I cannot use ObjectInputStream in the first place because my byte array contains first byte saying what to do with the desirealized object.

Everything was okey when I sent strings and other core objects.

Can you please point out where I have the error?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program we can use to reproduce the issue. Hint: the problem is likely to be *either* in the serialization *or* in the transmission. You should test each separately to work out which it is, and then only have the relevant one in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 03ACED00
```

A correct stream header would be `ACED00..`. So clearly you have the `03` byte left over from a previous deserialization. So you have a bug in your (undisclosed) byte-array reading code, which BTW should have looked like this:

```
int len = din.readInt();
byte[] data = new byte[len];
din.readFully(data);
```

etc.

**HOWEVER** There's no reason to use `ByteArrayInput/OutputStream` or `DataInput/OutputSream` here at all. Just use

```
new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
```

and

```
new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
```

where these are allocated once for the lifetime of each socket, and use `writeObject()` and `readObject()` directly. There's no advantage to the way you're doing it, just opportunities for bugs like this.

> I cannot use ObjectInputStream in the first place because my byte array contains first byte saying what to do with the desirealized object.

That's not correct. Just call `write()` with the tag byte, then `writeObject()`. At the peer, call `read()` to get the tag byte, then `readobject()`.

Evidently you've failed to remove the first byte before providing it to `new ObjectInputStream(...)`.

Comment: "A correct stream header would be ACED00... So clearly you have the 03 byte left over from a previous deserialization." I'm curious how do you know this? Is there a reason why a correct header won't start with 03 (that's also valid hex)?